# May one make obscene gestures?

Tags: halacha, language, speech-talking, hands-fingers

I was told that sign language does not qualify as actual speech (ergo one cannot make a beracha via sign language) as such would [obscene gestures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obscene_gesture) be permissible (since they would ostensibly not violate *nivel peh*, as they are not made by the mouth) or would they be forbidden for some other reason?

Comment: Kedoshim Tihiyu - Al Tihiye Naval B'Reshus HaTorah

Comment: If you do something with the intention of hurting/offending another person, what does it matter whether you did it with your speech or your actions?

Comment: @Bachrach44 I don't think he is discussing *onaas devarim*, but rather *nivul peh* ( *I'll admit that I don't fully understand the parameters of* either, *but that distinction might answer your question* )

Answer (score 2):

There is a Ben Yehoyada in כתובות דף ח ע׳ב who points out that Chazzal made a distinction between נבול פה, and כל המנבל פיו. The first refers to speaking perverse language, the second refers to making perverse gestures with one's tongue.

Comment: What does that have to do with making hand gestures?

Comment: @Shoket i think one can learn from there not to make obscene gestures with any body part, but chazzal picked one that was a common one, as he says there 'the way the scoffers do'. Feel free to disagree. And i plugged in the maareh makom. Had to check it up first.

Comment: I'll take a look -- thanks for finding the mareh makom. After I see it inside I'll see what I think of it.

Comment: I just love editing old questions and having them turn up with an answer in under ten minutes :-) ....apparently, you weren't here when this question was asked.

Comment: @Shokhet it is pretty amusing:) so you just go perusing through the old questions and are michata bigachalim by editing?

Comment: If I'm bored enough, yeah :)